# Javascript/Jquery Single event target delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I realized event.target redundancy could cause a lot of problems in the future when they are binded with another event in the next level.

For example, when i have an Div element inside another.

```
<div id='div1'>
  <div id='div2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use the follow Jquery code to bind an event.

```
$('div').bind('click', function(event){
   alert(event.target.id)
}
```

There are two alert boxes instead of one.
I understand the concept of why is because there are 2 divs I am clicking.

Of course the problem in a deeper level is that when I am trying to bind an event after this event accordingly with the event.target, it binds x2 so on and so forth.

Is it possible to get rid of the event binding on the outside div and only capture the inside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nick is right about using .stopPropagation(), but you're actually not doing event delegation here.  By using $('div'), you're attaching separate events to each of the div tags.  You want to use $('#div1') instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the event [from bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) using [`event.stopPropgation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) like this:

```
$('div').bind('click', function(event){
  alert(event.target.id);
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RvNvw/).  This will "trap" the `click` on the first `<div>` that gets it, and won't let it propagate up to any parents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to select the inside div in your bind call:

```
$('div:eq(0)').bind('click', function(event){
   alert(event.target.id)
}
```