# redundancy with multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem of redundancy with a jQuery multiple selector

here is my code:

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        <div id="3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
$("#1,#2,#3").on('click', function()
{
    alert("my message");
});
<script>
```

if i click on "3" i will have 3 times "my message" 
if i click on "2" i will have 2 times "my message" 
if i click on "1" i will have 1 times "my message"

But, i would like that any div I click, I only have 1 times "my message"

thank you for your help

Comment: And why don't you just bind event to the nearest common ancestor? If you provide any relevant use case, there is surely  better thing to do than binding mutliple click events

Comment: I always search before posting. But, I've never learnt the vocabulary because I never had a teacher. I learn alone and guys speaking like you make me feel offended

Comment: No offense from me, really. Here could be usefull to read: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop event propagation to child element:

```
$("#1,#2,#3").on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert("my message");
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript/Jquery Single event target delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3505757/722036)

Answer (score 0):

we should use simply return false also.

```
$("#id1,#id2,#id3").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```